# What's the best practice for call API

Tags: angularjs, express

What's the best practice for call the API ?

Client(Angularjs) -> Router -> API

Example

**Client**

```
   $http.post('/login', data, config).then(successCallback,errorCallback);
```

Express

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
              //some code
};
```

or

Client(Angularjs) -> API

call the API from client

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('SomeCtrl', ['$scope', 'user', '$state', function($scope, user){
        $scope.log = function(){
          User.login({}).$promise      //User.login is the API for login
          .then(function(user){
          });
        };
}]);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is probably to create a "model" which you include as a dependency in a controller. In this model (angular factory for example) you would call $http. This is the best approach for testing and reusability.

Comment: Also, a RESTful API should be made up of nouns (singular or plural is your choice) whereas "login" is a verb. I've seen a web app POST to "/" as a means of authentication, but I couldn't say if that is the best practice.

Comment: To be RESTful, one can use Restangular. I tried it once, it kinda makes you have your backend api also restful, which can be fine.

Comment: Restangular is for the front end, isn't updated to the current versions of Angular, and it also is not maintained anymore. The creator was looking for people to take it over last I looked. I wasn't really impressed with it, but had to use it for work. We are in the process of stripping it out.

Comment: Of course it is for frontend. Yeah, you are right, it wasn't a pleasure to use it. I also used for work, but  it was more like a test for us. Good luck with the stripping out your solution.